# How to indentify tests that are failing with mvn test

Tags: java, maven-surefire-plugin

I have setup maven and surefire for running unit tests. The test classes are configured to run in parallel; i.e. classes

Sometimes when I run "mvn test", some tests fail with a timeout. However, surefire doesn't log which tests were running when the timeout happened. It only logs details of tests that completed.

The timeout seems to be some kind of a deadlock and doesn't reproduce always.

How does one find out which tests were running when the timeout happened? Is there a way to change the log level of surefire itself so that it dumps some messages when it starts running test from a new class?

I am using: Java: 1.6, Maven: 3.0.3, Surefire: 2.14

Comment: Under `/target/surefire-reports`, there is test by test results...

Comment: target/surefire-reports only has logs of tests that completed. If "mvn test" failed because of a timeout, it doesn't log details of tests that were started but not completed. The failure I see is:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test (default-test) on project <project-name>: There was a timeout or other error in the fork -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1):

Execute the tests in debug mode

mvn -X test